# Run a second function only after the first function is completely finished

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Hi everyone I have such a problem,
I have 2 asynchronous functions.
I want only after the first is completely over, to run the second.
This is what I tried to do:

```js
  run2functions = async () => {
    await firstFunc();
    await secondFunc();
  };
  
  firstFunc = () => {
    console.log("first one");
    //Api code for information from any server

 }
 
  secondFunc = () => {
    console.log("second one");
    //Api code for information from any server

 }
 
 run2functions();
```

But it does not always work, sometimes the code of the second function runs before the code of the first function, I'm not sure why, I used await to force the second to be only after the first one ends.

I only want the first function to end now to activate the second function.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue - via the snippet runner at least

Comment: `firstFunc` and `secondFunc` are not promises

Comment: @MisterJojo Thanks for the comment, how can this be turned into promises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `async` the functions that are `await`able (return a Promise)

```js
// DEMO ONLY Just a helper to wait some ms time and return a Promise
const wait = (t) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, t)); 

const firstFunc = async () => {
  await wait(1000); // Just to fake some wait time
  console.log("first one");
}

const secondFunc = () => { // This does not need to be async
  console.log("second one");
}

const run2functions = async() => {
  await firstFunc();  // Await for this one
  secondFunc();       // You don't need to await for this one
};

run2functions();
```

Will result in:

```
(waiting 1 sec....)   
"first one"
"second one"
```

If you're waiting for **both** responses (i.e: one function takes 3sec to resolve, and the other one takes 2sec to resolve):
**use Promise.all**

```js
// DEMO ONLY Just a helper to wait some ms time and return a Promise
const fakeFetch = (time, data) => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(res, time, data)); 

// Functions that return a Promise (just like JS's fetch());
const one = () => fakeFetch( 3000, {message:"First!"} );
const two = () => fakeFetch( 2000, {message:"Second!"} );

Promise.all([one(), two()]).then((values) => {
  // After 5 sec...
  console.log(values); // In the exact order as the functions calls array
});
```

A **real-world example** of the above would be like:

```js
const getJSON = (url) => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()); // Returns a Promise
Promise.all([getJSON("users.json"), getJSON("tasks.json")]).then((JSONs) => {
  // After some unknown time... Both fetch Promises are resolved.  
  // Do some work with both JSON data:
  console.log(JSONs); // In the exact order as the functions calls array
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did not understand why there are 1000ms, is this a solution that will always work?

Comment: @dustyeav added a 1000ms wait time for demo, to make obvious that you'll not get in console `"second one" (wait 1 sec) "first one"` - but exactly as needed: `(wait 1 sec) "first one" "second one"`

Comment: Thank you, if I understood correctly, even if I write down 1ms, it's still supposed to work?

Comment: @dustyeav exactly. As long as it takes for firstFunc to resolve! 0.000N ms or N days does not matters ;)

Comment: @dustyeav you can mentally think of the line `await wait(1000);` exactly as being a `const users = await fetch("users.json"); return users;` - JS's `fetch()` also returns a Promise by default - just like we used a Promise faker using our silly `wait` function - it also returns a Promise. Does this explanation helps?

Comment: I think so, if I understood correctly, write the wait function to ensure 100% that the first function will end by the end, and only then will the second function work.
And can be put in the wait function - even 0ms.
I'm right?

Comment: @dustyeav no. The `wait` function I used above is just a stupid dummy function that returns a Promise which takes N time to complete - for the N time I used 1000ms just for demo. Remove that function from your code - it's not needed. I hope it's clear now. It could be anything.... for example a native JS `fetch()` which also returns a Promise and some **unknown** time to resolve . Anything that actually returns a Promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 2):

Async/await works only with fuctions which return `Promise`. So your code should look something like that:

```
const run2functions = async () => {
  await firstFunc();
  await secondFunc();
};

const firstFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    // your async code here
    console.log("first one");
    resolve(res);
  });
};

const secondFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    // your async code here
    console.log("second one");
    resolve(res);
  });
};

await run2functions();
```

**Additional resources**

- Async/await: https://javascript.info/async-await
- Promise: https://javascript.info/promise-basics

Comment: It should be`run2functions();` not `await run2functions();`

Comment: it doesn't matter here. I added the `await` only to suppress a linter error produced by my 
 IDE. IRL you would use `.then()`.

Answer (score 2):

If function one doesn't explicitly return a promise, and runs some async code, you can run into the situation you are describing.

You can solve this in two forms:

1 - Make `firstFunc` async and make it only finish after all code has run

```
const firstFunc = async () => {
  await getApiResponse();
  ...
}
```

2 - Make firstFunc return a Promise, that will make your main function properly await for it before moving on

```
const firstFunc = () => {
  return getApiResponse();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you tell me what to do with the second function? In the second function do not touch await or delete await?

Comment: The second function will run after. You should only use `await` if its an async function that you need finished before continuing with your code

Answer (score 0):

async function rango(){

```
let amp = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("First Promise");
    },2000);
 });


let volt = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Second Promise");
    },3000);
});

let a = await amp;
let v = await volt;

return[a,v];
```

}

rango();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```js
function run2functions() {
    firstFunc(secondFunc);
}

function firstFunc(cb) {
    setTimeout(() => {
    },1000);
    cb();
    console.log("first one");
}

function secondFunc() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("second one");
    },1000);
}
 
run2functions();
```

I have used the callback function for asynchronous operation. I have used setTimeOut function in both the firstFunct and secondFunct to prove my point that the secondFunct only executes after the firstFunct has completed its execution.
I hope this  helps...